# flutter stuck at Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-2010

Please  I need help. I tried my best but could not solve it. Here where it stuck

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

Comment: If you're using emulator, clean or reset it or create a new image. The usual flutter clean..etc

Answer (score 0):

try running `flutter clean` `flutter pub get` before running
sometimes the problem be from your emulator or pc. Mine sometimes run after 10mins which i don't know why  and if that doesn't work you might try creating a new project folder and run again if it still persist then file an issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you run the app before and stay in the background, you have two options:

1. Remove the app from background then run again
2. When the app reach the point of √ Built
   build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk. just open the app from
   mobile and you complete normally